# Hide images from user, restricting directory access

Tags: asp.net

Let's say my image is stored here:

```
C:\Users\linklee\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\mykladr\mykladr\images\temp\1.jpg
```

And I get them throw ashx file :

```
img.ImageUrl = "~/BackFile.ashx";
```

What I want to do is to hide this path:

```
http://localhost:50646/images/data/1.jpg
```

Where can I configure it?

Comment: Hide the path based on what condition? Or you want to hide it always?

Comment: yes hide the path always ...  for example if i type http://localhost:50646/images/data/1.jpg
 i want to get an error like restricted page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well either move them to directory that isn't subdirectory of your web application, or use forbidden handler to restrict access (assuming you're running in iis7+ and pool in integrated mode)

Web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <!-- ... -->
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.jpg" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

Comment: i got a mistake right now it's in russian sadly http://i.stack.imgur.com/4cEbw.jpg

Comment: `<system.web>
   
            <customErrors mode="Off"/>

 <httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.jpg" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
</httpHandlers> `       is it okay to put it here ?